# Do it really need specfic SUDO in crontab command line?

Tags: centos, cron

I am using CENTOS 7 with SELinux enabled.
The server has root account and 1 user account, 
In general, I use the root access and do everythings.

Today I try to config the cron job runs every night with the following command

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
========== Job 1 - Clear the access log ===========
55 23 * * * root truncate -s 0 /var/log/phpweb-datasync-access.log >/dev/null 2>&1
# ======== Job 2 Delete temp download photo from php web site===================
57 23 * * * root find /app/photo_store/ -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \; >/dev/null 2>&1
# ======== Job 3 Restart httpd Server ===========
59 23 * * * root sudo service httpd restart >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Everything is works, but I curious do I really need sudo in Job 3?
In case, I try to run "service httpd restart" in terminal, it has no permission issue, but I saw the cron job example on some tutorial site also has "sudo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running it from the `crontab` of `root`, which it looks like you are, then no, you don't need to specify `sudo` in the `cronjob`. It will run from root's shell with the appropriate rights and permissions and you've also already specified `root` in the cronjob itself.

In fact, if you run the job from `crontab -e` as `root` then you don't even need to specify `root` as the user. Using `sudo` won't cause any harm but it's not needed.

Answer (score 3):

From the [man page for crontab(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab):

```
Jobs in /etc/cron.d/

    The jobs in cron.d are system jobs, which are used usually for more than one
    user. That's the reason why is name of the user needed. MAILTO on the first 
    line is optional.


EXAMPLE FOR JOB IN /etc/cron.d/job

    #login as root
    #create job with preferred editor (e.g. vim)
    MAILTO=root
    * * * * * root touch /tmp/file
```

In your file, you are defining the user `root`, so the command will already be executed with elevated privileges.

The `sudo` is unnecessary.